# Python: Defining higher order functions(HOF) using other HOFs

Tags: python-3.x, higher-order-functions

I'm studying for mid-terms, and there is a fixed qns in the exam format. 
Higher order functions(HOF) is just a generalised function that takes in other functions to become more specific. The following are 2 higher order functions.

```
def tail(f, a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return tail(f, f(n, a), n-1)

def fold(op, f, n):
    if n==0:
        return f(0)
    else:
        return op(f(n), fold(op, f, n-1))
```

> My question is whether it's possible to define tail(as shown above)in terms of fold(as shown in the format below). If it's possible, can anyone suggest what are the expressions T1,T2,T3? If it is not possible, explain why.

```
def tail(f,a,n):
    return fold(<T1>,<T2>,<T3>)
```

I tried this problem for a long time, the following is the latest piece of code I reached, but still faces errors.

```
def tail2(f, a, n):  
    return fold(lambda n,a: a if n==0 else f(n,a),
                lambda n: f(n,a),
                n)
```

Test case: Tuple reversal

```
def test(seq,f, a, n):
    print(tail(f, a, n)) #test original func

    print(tail2(f, a, n)) #test invented func

x=(1,2,3,4,5)
print(test(x,lambda n,a: a+(x[n-1],),(),len(x)))
```